# Maintaining state of a program

Tags: c++, forms

This might be a simple question for most people out there but I'm like stuck on it.
I was wondering,most bank softwares or lets say any commercial software when closed at the end of the day and then re-opened the next,how do those programs remember everything from the previous day? I hope I make myself clear, thanks in advance for your guidance
Best.

Comment: Just bank software or any commercial software? I'd say most software tends to have some persistent state.

Comment: Use persistent memory like hard drives or just stay on. Saving state into persistent memory may be a big science of its own.

Comment: they do,but how,let say I have some thousand objects of different classes in the same program,when I run the program next day(after it is closed ofcourse) how'd I re-build those objects,I'm just stuck

Comment: as @AudriusMeškauskas says on Disk in a file - how do you save your own data? Photos, music etc... it's usually in a file - A database is basically files too - with an extra interface so you don't care what format the file is...

Comment: Serialize the data into binary format and store it in some database, then you unserialize it the next day. It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not black magic.

The answer is by saving its data.  You do this by putting it in a database, or writing data files.

The trick is to write your programs in a way that makes it easy to guarantee that you've restored the state you thought you saved.

A common approach is to use *serialization*.  This means that you are able to take your giant data structure and recursively call a 'Save' function on it and its contained objects.  This is very intuitive if you are taking advantage of object inheritance and polymorphism.  Of course, you also write a 'Load' function to do the reverse.

You write your data in such a way that it can be read back in.  For example, if you wanted to write a string, you might first write its length and then its characters.  That way, when you read it you know how many bytes to allocate.

The above approach is pretty standard if you are writing binary file formats.  In fact, it's the philosophy behind chunk-based formats such as AVI.

For text-based, you might choose to serialize your data in popular formats like XML or JSON.  But you are only restricted by your imagination.

Comment: Thanks paddy,I'm not that dumb as I sounded,I had same thing in mind except Serialization bit,thanks :)